# how to fix the randomized data for entire program in r

Tags: r, random, r-caret

I am working with iris data and I want to randomize/shuffle the data. The extract random 80% of the data to train. However each time I run my code I get a new order.

```
library(caret)
iris_data <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)), ]
set.seed(123)
training <- data[iris_data,]
testing <- data[-iris_data,]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `set.seed` needs to be called before `sample`

Comment: @konvas it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but `set.seed` has to be called before `sample`. The purpose of set seed is reproduce a set of pseudo random numbers. As sample will take some random points in iris, you have to set the seed before running it.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
iris_data <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)), ]
training <- data[iris_data,]
testing <- data[-iris_data,]
```